# How do I go about trying to validate a textbox upon pressing a button?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to think of ways to validate this textbox so that it will prevent users from entering numbers or special symbols. I want it so that, upon clicking the "Save" Button  (btnSaveJob), it will validate the textbox for the Name. The textbox is for entering names, so I'd like to try and validate it. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnSaveJob_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveJob.Click
    Dim txtName As TextBox

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) Then
    End If

    Try
        Dim result As DialogResult
        result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the selected job?", "Save Job",
 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
            Validate()
            TimetableBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.JobTimetableDataSet)
            MessageBox.Show("The Job has been saved successfully.", "Save Job", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            RefreshData()
            btnAddJob.Text = "Add New Job"

        Else
            'Exit Sub
            Return
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Save Job Failed: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
 "Save Job", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, why wait until they click the `Button`? WinForms controls have a `Validating` event that you can handle to prevent their leaving the control if it is invalid. Just set `e.Cancel` to `True` if the data is invalid and the control will refuse to lose focus. You can call `ValidateChildren` on the form in order to raise the event on every control, ensuring that those that never receive focus will also be validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as asked:

```vb
If txtName.Text.Any(Function(ch) Char.IsNumber(ch) OrElse Char.IsSymbol(ch)) Then
    'The text is invalid.
End If
```

That checkes whether any character is a number or a symbol. That may not be exactly what you want though. You can adjust the `Boolean` expression however you like, while the principle remains the same, e.g.

```vb
If txtName.Text.All(Function(ch) Char.IsLetter(ch) OrElse {" "c, "'"c}.Contains(ch)) Then
    'The text is valid.
End If
```

That last one checks that all characters are either letters, spaces or apostrophes. You can add whatever combination of conditions you want.